# Reacting to specific problems in CustomPolicy in CustomPage in ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

So, I am pretty new to ADB2C Custom Policies but here is what I have:

I have a Custom Policy with a few Technical Profiles.
I have a Custom Page with a bit of JavaScript.

The technical profile calls a REST API for some additional validation. The validation API returns an error code to ADB2C. But what I would need to do now is to display a link in reaction to a specific error returned by my validation API.

What would be the correct way to get an error code from my Validation API through my Technical Profile to my Custom Page and then react to that error in my own JavaScript? I am pretty sure you should be able to do this but I can't find any official Microsoft Documentation on that particular step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the error:

1. B2C service issue, static error issued to the app as described in the [Error codes: Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes). Also applies to an unhandled error not originating from B2C service, E.G: REST API does not respond, an error is returned to the app.
2. REST API returns an error in Validation technical profile - Error is shown to the user within the B2C page.

You can:

- 1: Get error details from the query parameters appended to your app reply url. EG: https://localhost:44316/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90075%3a+The+claims+exchange+%27REST-API-Endpoint%27+specified+in+step+%274%27+returned+HTTP+error+response+with+Code+%27BadRequest%27+and+Reason+%27Bad+Request%27.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+5b64bf9c-739b-4d1b-8bb2-d03f3fb7a811%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2020-05-07+00%3a46%3a42Z%0d%0a
- 2:

  - [Customize the api.error content definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#customize-the-default-azure-ad-b2c-pages) and do some javascript handling there.
  - Prefered option (also applicable to 1) is make API always return 200 but with response content including a success (boolan) and error related properties so that you can redirect the user to a [custom content screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#customize-the-default-azure-ad-b2c-pages) using [preconditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#preconditions-examples) based on the claims output from the aformentioned response properties.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank You!